# Why isn't my compiled kernel showing up in the GRUB boot menu?

Tags: arch-linux, linux-kernel, grub, grub2-mkconfig

I am trying to compile and install my own kernel (5.2.0-rc7) and everything seems to be working fine until I reboot to actually boot into it and am unable to select it from my GRUB boot menu. I have written a script (and done it manually with no difference) to compile and install for me based on the instructions [on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel/Traditional_compilation). Everything compiles without errors, `make modules_install` places the proper file in the /lib/modules folder and the proper images seem to be in the /boot directory. `mkinitcpio` completes without error and when I run `grub-mkconfig` it seems like it finds my newly installed custom kernel giving me this output:

```
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-linux
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
Found fallback initrd image(s) in /boot: initramfs-linux-fallback.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.2.0-rc7-test
Found initrd image: /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.2.0-rc7-test.img
done
```

And when I look at the generated `grub.cfg` file, I see that it does include the newly installed kernel as expected, shown below:

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
insmod part_gpt
insmod part_msdos
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos1'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos1' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
fi
terminal_input console
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
  set timeout_style=menu
  set timeout=5
# Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
# unavailable.
else
  set timeout=5
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
menuentry 'Arch Linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107' {
    load_video
    set gfxpayload=keep
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos1' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
    fi
    echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107 rw  quiet
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Arch Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107' {
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-advanced-9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos1' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107 rw  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-linux.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux linux (fallback initramfs)' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-linux-fallback-9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos1' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux linux ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107 rw  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initramfs-linux-fallback.img
    }
    menuentry 'Arch Linux, with Linux 5.2.0-rc7-test' --class arch --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.2.0-rc7-test-advanced-9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107' {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos1'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos1' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos1 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos1  9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.2.0-rc7-test ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.2.0-rc7-test root=UUID=9c56060e-d76c-4cea-8c41-137092164107 rw  quiet
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/intel-ucode.img /boot/initramfs-5.2.0-rc7-test.img
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

However, when I reboot my VM, I see that the Grub menu does not list the newly installed kernel only the standard one. According to the Arch wiki, all that needs to be done is to run the `grub-mkconfig` command to generate a new grub config file and if it is reflected in the config file it should show up but this doesn't seem to be the case.

What am I missing? **How can I get my newly installed kernel to show up in the Grub boot menu?** Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

I am doing this on Arch Linux running `5.1.16-arch1-1-ARCH` using Virtualbox 6.0.4 r128413

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have seen that your new kernel `Arch Linux, with Linux 5.2.0-rc7-test` is the third entry in submenu `Advanced options for Arch Linux`?

If it's still not showing, then try the following:

1. Press `c` in the grub menu for the command line
2. Enter `echo $prefix` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this should show your partition and path to `/boot/grub`. Verify that this is the correct partition.
3. Enter `cat $prefix/grub.cfg` <kbd>Enter</kbd>, this should show your current `grub.cfg`. If this is a different file, then there's something wrong with your grub installation.

Documentation:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#prefix

Comment: I'm an idiot, no I did not.  Thanks pointing that out.